# Image of minimal degree representation of quasisimple group unique up to conjugacy

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, finite-groups

Let $ G $ be a quasisimple finite group. Let $ d_{min} $ be the minimum dimension of a nontrivial irrep of $ G $. Must it be the case that the image of all (nontrivial) dimension $ d_{min} $ irreps of $ G $ are conjugate in $ SU(d_{min}) $?

For example all $ SL(2,5) $ subgroups of $ SU(2) $ are conjugate. This is especially interesting given that there are actually two distinct irreps of $ SL(2,5) $ into $ SU(2) $, they just happen to have conjugate image.

And I'm pretty sure that all $ A_5,GL(3,2) $ and $ 3.A_6 $ subgroups of $ SU(3) $ are conjugate.

And I'm pretty sure that all $ SL(2,9) \cong 2.A_6 , 2.A_7 $ and $ Sp(4,3) $ subgroups of $ SU(4) $ are also unique up to conjugacy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the Atlas, I'd say that the smallest counterexample is probably the Mathieu group $M_{11}$. There are three $10$-dimensional irreducible characters, not conjugate in $SU(10)$.

Edit: Actually, $L_2(8)$ is smaller, with four 7 dimensional irreducibles. Three of them are conjugate in $SU(7)$ but the fourth isn't. I somehow missed this, first time through. Similarly for $L_2(16)$.

Comment: Super! So how do you prove that the image of the $ PSL(2,8) $ representation with character $ (7,-1,-2,1,1,1,0,0,0) $ is not conjugate to the images of any of the other three degree $ 7 $ irreps?

Comment: Since the representation is irreducible, Schur's lemma shows that the only way the images can be conjugate is for there to be an automorphism that takes one character to the other.

Comment: Oh and the outer automorphism group of $ PSL(2,8) $ is size 3, that's lovely thank you!

Comment: In the case of $L_2(16)$, there are eight $15$-dimensional characters, and they fall into two orbits of size four under the automorphism group.

Comment: I think in $L_2(2^n)$ there are always $2^{n-1}$  $2^n-1$-dimensional characters, and each orbit has size dividing $n$, so the number of orbits increases rapidly, with the exact amount depending on the prime factorization of $n$.